# Number of possible outcomes in a combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics

There are 6 boxes, each holding 3 balls - red (R), green (G), and blue (B). Drawing 1 ball from each box,
 
a) how many possible outcomes are there to draw 4 red balls?
b) how many possible outcomes are there to draw X red balls?

I can easily work out that there is only 1 way to draw 6 red balls:

1. (R) (R) (R) (R) (R) (R)

I can also count that there are 12 different ways to draw 5 red balls:

1. (B) (R) (R) (R) (R) (R)
2. (G) (R) (R) (R) (R) (R)
3. (R) (B) (R) (R) (R) (R)
4. (R) (G) (R) (R) (R) (R)
5. (R) (R) (B) (R) (R) (R)
6. (R) (R) (G) (R) (R) (R)
7. (R) (R) (R) (B) (R) (R)
8. (R) (R) (R) (G) (R) (R)
9. (R) (R) (R) (R) (B) (R)
10. (R) (R) (R) (R) (G) (R)
11. (R) (R) (R) (R) (R) (B)
12. (R) (R) (R) (R) (R) (G)

However, when I go down in the number of red balls that are being drawn from the boxes, the number of distinct ways to draw them is increasing. I am struggling to formulate a general solution for any number of red balls being drawn. Please help :)

Comment: What exactly makes one outcome different from another? For example if we pulled out five red and one green, does it matter which box the green came from?

Comment: Yes it does. Sorry if I did not make that clear.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it is convenient to translate combinatorical problems in a different context one is more acquainted with.

You said that the position of the box is distinctive. So, basically each possible outcome in your experiment corresponds to a sequence of length $6$ consisting of the letters $R,G,B$.

Hence, to calculate the number of possible outcomes boils down to find the number of such sequences satisfying the given conditions:

- Number of ways to place $\color{blue}{X}$ letters $R$ in a sequence of length $\color{blue}{6}$: $\color{blue}{\binom{6}{X}}$
- Number of ways to fill the remaining $\color{blue}{6-X}$ places with any of the $\color{blue}{2}$ letters $G,B$: $\color{blue}{2^{6-X}}$

All together:

$$\mbox{Number of outcomes (sequences) containing $X$ red balls} = \color{blue}{\binom{6}{X}\cdot 2^{6-X}}$$

Comment: Thank you so much @trancelocation , this was exactly what I was trying to work out!

Comment: @IvanMajic : You are welcome :-)